# mongodb filter array with specific fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

Consider you have following collection:

```
{
    "_id": "5efcc5b4bff7b0abda626b04",
    "by_day": [
      {
        "date": {"$date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"},
        "metrics": {
          "impressions": 64864,
          "engagements": 1234,
          "link_clicks": 1057,
          "other_clicks": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "date": {"$date": "2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"},
        "metrics": {
          "impressions": 24882,
          "engagements": 2684,
          "link_clicks": 2056,
          "other_clicks": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "date": {"$date": "2020-01-03T00:00:00.000Z"},
        "metrics": {
          "impressions": 24882,
          "engagements": 2684,
          "link_clicks": 2056,
          "other_clicks": 2
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to filter `by_day` array for a date range with specific metrics ex:

```
{
    "_id": "5efcc5b4bff7b0abda626b04",
    "by_day": [
      {
        "date": {"$date": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"},
        "metrics": {
          "impressions": 64864,
          "engagements": 1234
        }
      },
      {
        "date": {"$date": "2020-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"},
        "metrics": {
          "impressions": 24882,
          "engagements": 2684          
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I tried following `$filter` aggregation but i could get only filter the date range for all metrics and can't find a way to filter metrics.

```
db.insights.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            by_day:{
                $filter: {
                    input: "$by_day",
                    cond: {
                        $and:[{$gte: [ "$$this.date", ISODate("2020-01-01") ]},
                            {$lte: [ "$$this.date", ISODate("2020-01-02") ]},
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

How to modify this query to filter metrics as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution.

```
db.insights.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            by_day:{
                $filter: {
                    input: "$by_day",
                    cond: {
                        $and:[{$gte: [ "$$this.date", ISODate("2020-01-01") ]},
                            {$lte: [ "$$this.date", ISODate("2020-01-02") ]},
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            by_day:{
                metrics:{
                    impressions:1,
                    engagements:1
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```